# jQuery Plugin Development - Keep track of all elements plugin has been applied to

Tags: jquery

How do you create a jQuery plugin that is able to access other elements it's been applied to?

What is meant is, if a custom plugin is applied via $('selector').test(), test may add an event click to all elements matched by 'selector'.

Within this click event some action needs to be performed on all other elements matched by 'selector', what is the best way to go about doing this?

The following is a working example:

- it will apply a click event to all spans,
- on click it will log all other elements that test has been applied to.

-

```
$.fn.test = function() {
    var children = [];
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).css('color','green').on('click',function() {
            console.log(children);
        });
        children.push(this);
    });
};

$('span').test()
```

Although this example works, is this best practice? The jQuery document on plugin development don't seem to cover this topic.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does the eventListener not already get applied to all the other elements with the same selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/7w2Rq/)***

It isn't bad practice per se, but it can be improved a little. Internally jQuery will iterate over a set, and the `this` inside of the `jQuery.fn` is the whole set of the selector response so you don't need to use each and then rewrap them individually

```
$.fn.test = function() {
    var set = this;
    return this.css('color','green').on('click',function() {
        console.log(set.not(this));
    });
};

$('span').test()
```

Comment: Thanks, what if this.css(..).on(..) was replaced with new DoSomething($(this)); Where DoSomething applies the css and click event?  It's the click within DoSomething that needs to get the other elements. DoSomething can only take a single element at a time.

Comment: @lookbadgers - Inside of the click event callback, `this` refers to one element. Since `set` was cached, that is the parent group of all the matched elements. Between those two, you should still be able to handle any scenario involving those groups. If you would like to use only the clicked element, then work with `this` inside of the function callback for the click event.

Comment: Thank you that's much simpler then my original example.